# ASP.NET Core MVC & EF Core: "Failed creating connection: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string

I get the error when updating or dropping the database

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=AvcolMusic;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

`ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MusicContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    //throw new Exception(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

    services.AddIdentity<ACUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
             .AddDefaultUI()
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MusicContext>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

I clicked on a painful amount of Google links, but none of them have fixed my problem.

All advice says to use the connection string that I already have, or to format `AddDbContext` in the way that I already have.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Check you connection string http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm

Comment: This does not make any sense "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB"  Local db is the default folder on the machine where the database is located (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\LocalDB\Binn).  Using two backslashes is the root location on the driver.  Then you should never use Localdb when a database is attached to a server.  use Sever when database is attached and localdb when the mdf file is not attached.  The folder where the database is located when attached is inside the server and does not need to be part of the connection string.   All you need is the server name and database name.